# How to pass parameters with php in my case

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting an `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"` error when try to load a page with a php variable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $.get("index.html", {token:<?php echo $token; ?>}, function(data) {
                 //codes..
               });
 });
```

I can't seem to echo `$token` in my javascript and I am sure $token is valid.

Can someone help me solve this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is token a string? `{token:'<?php echo $token; ?>'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're echoing text from PHP into a Javascript context, which means you have to generate valid Javascript code. Simplest solution: json_encode()

```
{token : <?php echo json_encode($token) ?>}
```

json_encode() will take care of any quoting/escaping which needs to be done.

e.g. if `$token = 'foo'`, then you'd be producing

```
{token: foo}
```

and be producing an undefined variable error.

Answer (score 1):

you need to put quotes around the php output otherwise it will be treated as a javascript variable rather than a string

```
{token:'<?php echo $token; ?>'}
```